# qpython keyboard missing backspace

Tags: qpython

I am running qpython on my Samsung S4 and when I start the console it starts with python running and I get a keyboard with no BS key. Also, if I try to use the Special keys by using (e.g.) the Vol-UP W to invoke the UP key I get the Esc sequence. Can anyone please tell me how to properly setup the console and keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround can be installing [Hacker's keyboard](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzu_XQm9TMAhUG2ywKHY7FDC4QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dorg.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard%26hl%3Dfi&usg=AFQjCNERkRM5eCGSXbGWj7VpUtxDA8ly2w&sig2=1qGGrjNIZXOCU3Q0nInRxA) for android and forget about Vol-Up, -Down keys.

Comment: Link only answer is not encouraged